# Multiple simultaneous visualizations from same data source in Azure Workbooks (Application Insights)

Tags: azure-monitor-workbooks

I am having trouble with Azure workbooks (for Application Insights), trying to get the same data displayed with different visualizations **at the same time**.

I may have a simple query like:

```
requests 
 | where timestamp > ago(24h) 
 | summarize count() by client_CountryOrRegion
 | top 10 by count_ 
 | render piechart
```

But now I want to also render the same data as a `table` without copy/pasting the 'algorithm' (which clearly in reality is more complicated than this sample). So I want to effectively do this:

```
let data = requests 
 | where timestamp > ago(24h) 
 | summarize count() by client_CountryOrRegion
 | top 10 by count_ ;

 data | render table;
 data | render piechart;
```

But this just renders the first visualization.

I've tried everything I can think of:

- Just put the second visualization in a new step, but I can't find a way to reference this `data` parameter.
- Create a multi value parameter fed from a query and then tried to use it in a subsequent step. That didn't work.

  {data} | render piechart
- Create a global parameter and try to set it from a step. Doesn't seem to be a way to explicitly set a parameter value from a query step.
- Tried to name the step under the advanced tab, but I can't find any example of how to reference the step in future steps despite this message.

[image]

There must be a way not to have to maintain two copies of the query, but I wasn't able to find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The workbooks steps do not understand things like the `fork` operator which can return many tables of data, it only knows how to visualize the first table.

The easiest way to get what you want is to use a [`merge` data source] to duplicate a query result (https://github.com/microsoft/Application-Insights-Workbooks/blob/master/Documentation/DataSources/DataSources.md#merge-data-from-different-sources)

1. Create your query, returning all the columns you want, vizualized the way you want.
   Give it a useful name, like you've shown in the screenshot.
2. Add another query step, this time in the data source dropdown, choose `merge`
3. in the merge step's setting, use the "Add Merge" option, and in the popup that appears, chose the merge type "Duplicate Table", and pick the step named in step 1
4. the merge step allows you to add calculated columns as well, if you need to do math on 2 other columns, like computing percentages/rates, etc.  use the "add new item" item in the toolbar of the merge step.  you can also rename, reorder, remove columns of data
5. then run the merge step and choose the other visualization

The merge step can do other kinds of merges/unions/joins as well, between disparate sources.  so you can merge together data from Azure Resource Graph (like properties/tags) with data from metrics, and data from logs into one grid.  And the merge step can do all of that work in just one merge step, you don't need to add multiple merge steps (x = a union b, then another step of y = x union c, you can do it as multiple joins/unions in the one merge step.),

if you use merge this way to join/union data sources, you can hide the original sources, and the merge will still work.  however, merges cannot depend on hidden *merges* yet, hence my suggestion that people use *one* merge step that does multiple joins instead of multiple merge steps that each do one.